# Simulate C macro in Python

Tags: python, string, variables, format, resolve

How can I automagically resolve format specifiers in Python?
For example instead of:

```
MagicPrint(str.format('This is {}', my.name))
```

I want to write MagicPrint() function as follows:

```
MagicPrint('This is {my.name}')
```

Suggestions? Maybe I can use decorators for `MagicPrint()` function?
Please note that `my.name` is not present in `**locals()` because `MagicPrint()` can be called from another module.

Comment: Its impossible! actually  [there are  2 way for putting variable within a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) 1. is `format` and 2. using `%` notations.`'This is %s'% my.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
class my: name = "Jerry"
"This is {my.name}".format(**locals())
```

Comment: That will only work when \**locals() contains the my.name variable. I am looking for a method that receives `my.name` from another module.

Comment: You might want to put that in your question. You could also use `vars(modulename)` to get the variables from that module.

Answer (score 0):

that only work on `**locals()` contains . I am looking for a method that receives `a.class_name` from another module.

```
class a: class_name = "name_class"
"This is {a.class_name}".format(**locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038160/how-to-get-module-variable-in-function-from-another-module/2038210#2038210) solution to access caller's variables.
Then I have automagical access to print the string.

```
def MagicPrint(s, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' In order for this to work we need the caller's module variables '''
    f = sys._getframe(1) 
    try:
        print (s.format(*args, **f.f_globals))
    except:
        print (s.format(*args, **f.f_locals))
    else:
        pass
```